# Limit string list add

Tags: c#, string, list

Hi stack overflow users,
I have created a fully functional Hangman Game in C# now I am polishing the last parts before handing the assignment in.
I decided to create three different difficulties "Easy" "Medium" "Hard" instead of letting the user pick the amount of life.
Now to the question?
Is there a function to add words into the word list (which then get randomly selected by a method)? I would like to limit the min and max length of the words that the user adds onto the list of words.
Below is the class for my WordList.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class WordList
{
    public static list <string>word = new list<string>();

    public void Showwordlist()
    {
        word.sort();
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            console.WriteLine("- " + word);
        }
    }

    public void Addwords(string input)
    {
        word.add(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add functionality inside the Addowrds() methods that checks the length of the input string.

Comment: in `Addwords` Don't `word.add(input);` if `input.Length` is too long or too short?

Comment: Is your problem more of the "let the user know whats wrong" kind?

Comment: `Now to the question?` but you still don't ask a question...

Comment: How is this "fully functional"?  `Console`, `List` and `Sort` aren't capitalized properly, and you aren't capturing the output of `Sort()`.

Comment: It's possible that the code was typed into the question editor and not copied and pasted from his actual code.

Comment: Hi D.stanley, all my variables and methods are in swedish, I translated it to english quick without capitalized and proper setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a check to see if it meets the minimum length and is less than the maximum length:

```
private int minimumLength = 4;
private int maximumLength = 20;

public void Addwords(string input)
{
    if(input.Length >= minimumLength && input.Length <= maximumLength)
        word.add(input);
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Word length must be between " + minimumLength + 
                         @" and " maximumLength + " characters");
}
```

I'm assuming that the bounds are all inclusive so I'm using the `>=` and `<=` operators. The `MessageBox.Show` is assuming that you're using Windows Forms. Otherwise, handle the error message appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Cameron, your solution fixed the problem all the way. I really do appreciate the level of detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!

Comment: No problem. If you accidentally downvoted, you can retract your downvote by clicking the down arrow again or by clicking the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
public void Addwords(string input)
{
    if(input.Length < minLength)
        throw new Exception("Too Short");  // example only - throw a better exception
    if(input.Length > maxLength)
        throw new Exception("Too Long");   // example only - throw a better exception

    word.add(input);
}
```

Comment: Meh. Not sure I would throw and exception rather than something like what Cameron has.

Comment: Thanks D Stanley for a nice explaination of the code.

Comment: tnw, would you mind explaining the biggest pros and cons on exceptions vs using ex console.write("");
or messagebox?.

Comment: I was only using it as an example - you need to decide what you want to _do_ if an invalid word is added.  That will determine whether an exception or other notification is appropriate.  You need _some_ sort of feedback for an invalid input - whether it's an exception, messagebox, returning a bool, etc. is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RegularExpressions to limit the characters used in the words as well as the length.  In the regular expression below, only words that contain upper and lower case letters that are between 2 and 10 characters would be allowed.

```
public void Addwords(string input)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, "^[a-zA-Z.]{2,10}$");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        word.add(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for another example, whats the difference between regex, they have not talked anything about regex in the course jet.

Comment: The difference between regex and ??? Go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx.  This is a good starting place to read about regex.

Comment: When to use en regex for managing limits and when to ex use variabels like min and max?.